# UICollectionView, paging, and clipsToBounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview

I've got a collection view whose content is scrolled horizontally and needs to be visible for the full width of the device. The collection view has `clipsToBounds` set to `NO` and it's frame is `600` wide with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`.

The effect I'm looking for is that content would appear to slide under another view, however when the cell is scrolled outside the frame of the collection view then it is removed so that it can be reused.

Anyone know how I might get this to work, or achieve a similar effect?

Comment: can u plz provide more details. e.g code snippet any or wireframe or you hv tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16070570

Comment: I tried something like this but I think I failed to disable the native recognizer, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6):

Below is the simplest way that I've found to get this effect. It involves your collection view and an extra secret scroll view.

**Set up your collection views**

- Set up your collection view and all its data source methods.
- Frame the collection view; it should span the full width that you want to be visible.
- Set the collection view's `contentInset`:

  ```
  _collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.width-pageSize)/2, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width-pageSize)/2);
  ```

This helps offset the cells properly.

**Set up your secret scrollview**

- Create a scrollview, place it wherever you like. You can set it to `hidden` if you like.
- Set the size of the scrollview's bounds to the desired size of your page.
- Set yourself as the delegate of the scrollview.
- Set its `contentSize` to the expected content size of your collection view.

**Move your gesture recognizer**

- Add the secret scrollview's gesture recognizer to the collection view, and disable the collection view's gesture recognizer:

  ```
  [_collectionView addGestureRecognizer:_secretScrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
  _collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
  ```

**Delegate**

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.x = contentOffset.x - _collectionView.contentInset.left;
    _collectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
}
```

As the scrollview moves, get its offset and set it to the offset of the collection view.

I blogged about this here, so check this link for updates: http://khanlou.com/2013/04/paging-a-overflowing-collection-view/